# Why isn't PyCharm working with my requirements.txt

Tags: pycharm, requirements.txt

I have a `requirements.txt` file with directories and libraries I would like imported into my PyCharm project. The problem is that in the PyCharm window I do not see the `requirements.txt`. I have stored the `requirements.txt` file in a directory I created for my PyCharm programs and I think this may be the problem.

I have tried navigating through "PyCharm | Preferences | Tools | Python Integrated Tools" and then entering the path to my `requirements.txt` file in the empty space labeled "Package requirements file" but my imports are still unrecognized. There is no notification to install packages listed in the `requirements.txt`.

This is the directory I have the file stored in:

```
~/PyCharm/<project name>$
requirements.txt   venv
```

If anyone has any ideas on how or where I should store my requirements.txt file please reach out.

Comment: What packages are listed in `File - Settings - Project Interpreter`? Are there any from `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements.txt should be in your specific project folder. You should be able to find it in your 'PycharmProjects' folder with the name of your project. So if you created a project called 'TestProject' place your requirements.text in the '...\PycharmProjects\TestProject' folder.

You can learn more about this on JetBrain's website https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-dependencies.html . It will show you how to manage your requirements.txt through PyCharm and also if you are unable to locate the directory you can follow the first set of instructions and just manually copy your requirements into the projects requirements.txt .